# storage of custom properties in a exchange public folder - Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server

I need to store a custom properties in a exchange public folder. I tried to use PropertyAccessor of MapiFolder, as well as the method GetStorage. But these remedies do not work. 
How to I can store a my custom properties in a exchange public folder?

Comment: What is the exact error returned by GetStorage?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko GetStorage returned an exception of type '_System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException_'. Additional information: "_Unable to create a storage element in this folder. Or folder is read-only, or storage of items in this folder are not allowed._" But folder is not read-only. This folder is shared to me and I have owner permissions for folder.

Answer (score 0):

Efim,

Do you get any exception or error in the code? Could you please be more specific?

Anyway, try to enable scripts in Public folders. See the Trust Center settings in Outlook.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply. I get an exception when trying to invoke a method GetStorage. The code is: 
`var mfolder = GetMapiFolder();
UserProperty property = null;
var storage = mfolder.GetStorage("TestStorage", OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyBySubject);`

Comment: Did you try to enable scripts in Publis folders?

Comment: Yes, I enabled scripts in Public folder, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.getstorage(v=office.14).aspx:

GetStorage returns an error if the store type of the folder is not supported. The following stores return an error when GetStorage is called:

•Hotmail store

•Internet Message Access Protocol (IMAP) stores

•Delegate stores

•**Public folder stores**

---

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, its [RDOFolder](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm).`HiddenItems.Add` will work on any kind of store as long as the store provider supports it and the user has sufficient priviledges.